# Hadoop - Reducer is waiting for Mapper inputs?

Tags: hadoop, local, reduce

as explained in the title, when i execute my Hadoop Program (and debug it in local mode) the following happens:

***1. All 10 csv-lines in my test data are handled correctly in the Mapper, the Partitioner and the RawComperator(OutputKeyComparatorClass) that is called after the map-step. But the OutputValueGroupingComparatorClass's and the ReduceClass's functions do NOT get executed afterwards.***

***2. My application looks like the following. (due to space constraints i omit the implementation of the classes i used as configuration parameters, til somebody has an idea, that involves them):***

```
public class RetweetApplication {

    public static int DEBUG = 1;
    static String INPUT = "/home/ema/INPUT-H";
    static String OUTPUT = "/home/ema/OUTPUT-H "+ (new Date()).toString();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(RetweetApplication.class);


    if(DEBUG > 0){
        conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
        conf.set("dfs.replication", "1");
    }


    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(INPUT));   
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(OUTPUT));


    //conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    //conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(RetweetMapper.class);
    conf.setPartitionerClass(TweetPartitioner.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(TwitterValueGroupingComparator.class);
    conf.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(TwitterKeyGroupingComparator.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(RetweetReducer.class);

    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    client.setConf(conf);
    try {
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

***3. I get the following console output(sorry for the format, but somehow this log doesnt get formatted correctly):***

> 12/05/22 03:51:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100 12/05/22
>   03:51:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   file:/home/ema/INPUT-H/tweets:0+967 12/05/22 03:51:12 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 0%
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   file:/home/ema/INPUT-H/tweets:0+967 12/05/22 03:51:15 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:15 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0
>   is done. And is in the process of commiting
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 0%
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   file:/home/ema/INPUT-H/tweets:0+967
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   file:/home/ema/INPUT-H/tweets:0+967
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.Task: Task
>   'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin :
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@35eed0
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: ShuffleRamManager:
>   MemoryLimit=709551680, MaxSingleShuffleLimit=177387920
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask:
>   attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging
>   on-disk files
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask:
>   attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread waiting: Thread for merging
>   on-disk files
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask:
>   attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging in
>   memory files
>
> **12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 0 is
>   already in progress  12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask:
>   attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0
>   dup hosts)**
>
> 12/05/22 03:51:17 INFO mapred.ReduceTask:
>   attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for polling Map
>   Completion Events
>
> **12/05/22 03:51:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0% 12/05/22 03:51:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > copy >**

The bold marked lines repeat endlessly from this point.

***4. Alot of open processes are active after the mapper saw every tuple:***

```
RetweetApplication (1) [Remote Java Application]    
    OpenJDK Client VM[localhost:5002]   
        Thread [main] (Running) 
        Thread [Thread-2] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [communication thread] (Running)  
        Thread [MapOutputCopier attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0.0] (Running)  
        Thread [MapOutputCopier attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0.1] (Running)  
        Thread [MapOutputCopier attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0.2] (Running)  
        Thread [MapOutputCopier attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0.4] (Running)  
        Thread [MapOutputCopier attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0.3] (Running)  
        Daemon Thread [Thread for merging on-disk files] (Running)  
        Daemon Thread [Thread for merging in memory files] (Running)    
        Daemon Thread [Thread for polling Map Completion Events] (Running)
```

Is there any reason, why Hadoop expects more output from the mapper (see the bold marked lines in the log) than i put into the input directory? As already mentioned, i debugged that ALL inputs are properly processed in the mapper/partitioner/etc.

**UPDATE**
With the help of Chris (see comments) i found out, that my program was NOT started in localMode as i expected it: the `isLocal` variable in the `ReduceTask` class is set to `false`, though it should be `true`.

To me it is absolutely unclear why this happens, since the 3 options that have to be set to enable the standalone mode were set the right way. Surprisingly: tho the `local` setting was ignored, the "read from normal disc" setting wasnt, which is very strange imho, because i thought `local` mode and the `file:///` protocol are coupled.

During debugging `ReduceTask` i set the `isLocal` variable to true by evaluating `isLocal=true` in my debug view and then tried to execute the rest of the program. It did not work out and this is the stacktrace:

```
12/05/22 14:28:28 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/05/22 14:28:28 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
12/05/22 14:28:28 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 1956 bytes
12/05/22 14:28:28 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/05/22 14:28:29 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.default.name;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:29 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.job.tracker;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 5 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 6 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 7 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 8 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/127.0.0.1:9001. Already tried 9 time(s).
12/05/22 14:28:39 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.default.name;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:39 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.job.tracker;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:39 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.net.ConnectException: Call to master/127.0.0.1:9001 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1095)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1046)
    ... 17 more
12/05/22 14:28:39 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.default.name;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:39 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.job.tracker;  Ignoring.
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 20
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=967
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=14093
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=47859
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=1960
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=10
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=10
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=1934
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=115937280
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=967
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=82
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=10
12/05/22 14:28:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
    at uni.kassel.macek.rtprep.RetweetApplication.main(RetweetApplication.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Since this stacktrace now shows me, that the port 9001 is used during execution, i guess that somehow the xml-configuration file overwrites the local-java-made setting (which i use for testing), which is strange since i read over and over on the internet, that java overwrites xml configuration. If nobody knows how to correct this, ill try to simply erase all configuration-xmls. Perhaps this solves the problem...

**NEW UPDATE**

Renaming Hadoops `conf` folder solved the problem of the waiting copier and the program is executed til the end. Sadly the execution doesnt wait anymore for my debugger although `HADOOP_OPTS` is set correctly.

RESUME:Its only a configuration issue: XML may (for some configuration parameters) overwrite JAVA. If somebody knew how i can get debugging to run again, it would be perfect, but for now im just glad i dont see this stacktrace anymore! ;)

Thank you Chris for your time and effords!

Comment: you certainly have something odd going on as the MapOutputCopier threads shouldn't be running in local mode. What version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your reply! I am using V1.0.2 and i didnt start the demons. When i execute jps i only see no other demon than jps running.

Comment: Are you able to pastebin your full driver code?

Comment: What is this "driver"? You mean the other involved classes?

Comment: The first block of code you posted is typically known as the driver - the class which contains the `main(String args[])` block, and should extend the `Configured` class, and implement the `Tool` interface

Comment: Ok, the full driver will be added now. Thanks for your explanation. :)

Comment: If you're able to insert breakpoints, you should put one in the `ReduceTask.run` method, aroung the `boolean isLocal = ...` line:382, as this appears to be resolving to false, triggering the copy threads. It should be resolving to true

Comment: Ok, ill do those subtyping as you supposed for a proper version. But i am currently just adopting examples i saw in books and in the inet, where this was not mandatory. But if you think, this is really important, ill add those.

Comment: I inserted breakpoints in all classes i use in my driver. They sadly never stop in the ReduceTask.run method. :(

Comment: Ahh i see, if i got the sources, i should debug into the framework. Well i suppose i could do that! :) Thanks alot for this hint!! I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Hi Chris, well i tried to get the sources of hadoop-core namely "hadoop-core-sources" (maven package), but couldnt find it anywhere. The only possibility to get source code, i could find, was to use SVN/GIT/etc to get the latest (probably unstable) code versions and other older versions which are not for available as binary versions. But i tested my code with 0.20.205.0/1.0.2/1.0.3: for all those versions the MapOutputCopier was activated. Did i forget some configuration-properties except for the 3 i set within the conditional block (DEBUG>1)?

Comment: Heres a script to build yourself a source jar http://whiteycode.blogspot.com/2012/05/building-hadoop-source-jars.html

Comment: Hi Chris, well i used your script and it built a jar, but somehow there were all files included, that also were in the src folder itself. When i added the jar as a library, the included classes were not found in my program. I then tried to build the complete hadoop project via mvn. Sadly doesnt go smoothly, since you seem to have to run the tests: testGracefulFailover and testOneOfEverything are actually failing. Isnt there any possibility to just let hadoop run in local mode without getting the workspace ready to compile hadoop itself?

Comment: Ok, i did debug to the line. I did not use the sources fitting to the lib i used, but i set the breakpoint in ReduceTast in **line 382** and this is exactly the line where `isLocal` is defined. And in my case it is false... so i guess the framework doesnt get what i want it to do!? But what am i doing wrong? I thought by setting those parameters in Java there cant go anything wrong. Also no demons were required to start mapreduce up to the reduce point AND the inputs were read locally and NOT from hdfs. I fear something is terribly wrong with me or the framework... i bet its me ;).

Comment: Are you able to post _ALL_ your code somewhere (github, pastebin)? You've certainly sparked my interest!

Comment: Oh, i like to hear that. :) Tomorrow i will add the classes' interfaces and some of the relevant Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i didn't see this before, but you appear to have two important configuration properties set to final in your conf xml files, as denoted by the following log statements:

> ```
> 12/05/22 14:28:29 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: fs.default.name;  Ignoring.
> 12/05/22 14:28:29 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-ema/mapred/local/localRunner/job_local_0001.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.job.tracker;  Ignoring.
> ```

This means that your job is unable to actually run in local mode, it starts in local mode, but the reducer reads the serialized job configuration and determines it is not in local mode, and tried to fetch map outputs via the task tracker ports.

You said your fix was to rename the conf folder - this will default hadoop back to the default configuration, where these two properties are not marked as 'final'